How to join two table in Snowflake SQL and use field variable from joined table as a filter in WHERE clause?
I have the following Query which is used to summarize the amount of partial cases per wave:
SELECT Wave_No, SUM(CASE WHEN Total_Qty != Consumed_Qty THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS Partial_Cases, 
    COUNT(*) AS Total_Cases, Partial_Cases/ Total_Cases AS Partial_Case_Percentage, 
    Creation_Date, Work_Group, Work_Area 
FROM Wave_Table
WHERE Status = '90'
AND Wave_No >= '20240701024'
AND Work_Group LIKE '%SOR%'
GROUP BY Wave_No, Creation_Date, Work_Group, Work_Area
ORDER BY Wave_No

In Wave_Table there is field called "Style_No" which has a numeric code for style of the product. In this database, there is other table called "Product_Table" which has field called "Product_Style". This field has the same information as of "Style_No" from "Wave_Table". I would like to join "Product_Table" to "Wave_Table" using the common field with different name mentioned above and use the other variable called "Style_Code" from "Product_Table" as filter. That filter will be Style_Code IN (‘A’, ‘B’, ‘C’) > 5
I have tried to use left outer join but I cannot figure out the Syntax for it and also based on other threads, this is little bit different so I am having a hard time replicating that logic over here. Any help would be appreciated. Thanks.
Pic represent the table and joining.


What does this mean?  Style_Code IN (‘A’, ‘B’, ‘C’) > 5

it would be better if you would have give some sample data and expected out put. You can try this on the information provided by you.
--Not tested
  SELECT Wave_No, SUM(CASE WHEN Total_Qty != Consumed_Qty THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS Partial_Cases, 
        COUNT(*) AS Total_Cases, Partial_Cases/ Total_Cases AS Partial_Case_Percentage, 
        Creation_Date, Work_Group, Work_Area 
    FROM Wave_Table WT
    JOIN  Product_Table PT ON PT.Product_Style = WT.Style_No
    WHERE WT.Status = '90'
    AND WT.Wave_No >= '20240701024'
    AND WT.Work_Group LIKE '%SOR%'
AND WT.Style_Code IN (‘A’, ‘B’, ‘C’) --> 5
    GROUP BY WT.Wave_No, WT.Creation_Date, WT.Work_Group, WT.Work_Area
    ORDER BY Wave_No

Also any idea what is this > 5 in your condition that youw wanted to add " Style_Code IN (‘A’, ‘B’, ‘C’) > 5"

Thank you so much Himanshu, I have tried the Query. Its working but the results are not correct. The numbers of Partial and Total case are 1000 times more.

Please check your Join conditions , are you missing any columns in your join,  also if you sent some sample data / expected output that would help.

Yes, I figured out your suggestion. Unfortunately there is no other column that I can use to drill down for the result but the joining is worked.
